# Any simpler way to make a lazy property?

Tags: f#

I would like to load data only when needed.

At start I used auto property.

```
type DataFromCsv(path) =
    ...
    member val A1 = MyCsvType.Load(path1)
    member val A2 = MyCsvType.Load(path2)
    member val A3 = MyCsvType.Load(path3)
    member val A4 = MyCsvType.Load(path4)
```

It is sort of lazy till I instantiate the object `let my_data = DataFromCsv(path)`, at which time all the files are loaded, which is not ideal.

My another attempt is to use `lazy` for each property.

```
type DataFromCsv(path) =
    let a1 = lazy (MyCsvType.Load(path1))
    let a2 = lazy (MyCsvType.Load(path2))
    member this.A1 = a1.Force()
    member this.A2 = a2.Force()
```

It works, but I feel it is a bit cumbersome. Furthermore, `a1` is only used by `member this.A1` but it is visible anywhere in the object.

So, is there a kind of auto lazy property, so that I can do such things more elegantly?

Comment: I don't think there is a one-liner for this. Though you could probably do some meta-programming kung-fu like this: https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/fsharp-wpf-mvc-series/wiki/Model